# Unable to send email through SPutility.sendemail

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sputility, send-email

unable to send a mail  through **system.net** api and **sputility.sendmeail()** .

I  tried the below code for sending mail through the above. but it failed to send  mail.
 But  if I tried with PowerShell approach , I am able to send mails without any issues.

**SPutility code :**

```
    try
        {

            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite msite = new SPSite("http://sharepointuat:400/sites/dms"))
                {
                    using (SPWeb mweb = msite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        string from = "dmsadmin@mydomain.in";

                        string to = "user11@incompany.com;user2201@incompany.com";
                        string cc = "user33@incompany.com";
                        string bcc = "";
                        string subject = "hello sendmail from SP 2010  THRU SPUTILITY";
                        string body = "hello sendmail from SP 2010  THRU SPUTILITY";

                        string emailSummary;
                        var messageHeaders = new StringDictionary();

                        messageHeaders.Add("to", to);
                        messageHeaders.Add("from", from);
                        messageHeaders.Add("subject", subject);
                        messageHeaders.Add("cc", cc);
                        messageHeaders.Add("bcc", bcc);
                        string mimeType = "text/html";
                        messageHeaders.Add("content-type", mimeType);


                        bool sendMail = SPUtility.SendEmail(mweb, messageHeaders, body)


                      //[Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::SendEmail($web,0,0,$email,$subject,$body)



                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception exp11)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exp11.Message + "__"  + exp11.StackTrace);
            throw exp11;
        }
```

Powershell code  which is working:

```
 #add-pssnapin "microsoft.sharepoint.powershell"
   $email = "a@in.com;s@in.com"
   $subject = "mail.domain test subject1111"
    $body = "Test body2222 sending mail to S n p"
    $site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite                
       "http://sharepointuat:400/sites/DMS"
        $web = $site.OpenWeb()
         [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::SendEmail($web,0,0,
            $email,$subject,$body)
```

The above PowerShell code is working fine.

I am in need of sending mail through **sputility**, **C#** & **SharePoint SSOM**.

Can anyone help , whether I am missing any parameter missing from my C# code?

Comment: The documentation for SPUtility.SendEmail method says "This method supports sending email messages only to valid SharePoint user email addresses.", https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460489.aspx, are the addresses in TO header valid SharePoint user email addresses?

Comment: Yes.of course. The strange thing is that, it works in powershell. I have checked with correct valid user email ids only. Any other settings I need to do?

Comment: Is this a console/windows app code or a web app code running on IIS?

Comment: For testing purposes I created a simple console application. But my actual environment is visual web part targeting in  SP 2010 env

Comment: even i tried with the system.net smtp.sendmail() as well. that also failed in sending the mail to target users! So is there any issue with smtp server? i for the sputility object,i have correctly mentioned/configured the outgoing emailsettings in my central admin. thats the reason thru powershell, i am able to send mails,but why sputility is not taking/reading the outgoing mail settings. v.strange issue.

Comment: i have this code in my visual web part and i am writing the code for sending the mail to a group of users. here its not working. another approach of calling a powershell script that does the sendmail, from visual web part seems a complex one and am not sure about the success.

Comment: Please debug and check if `sendMail` variable returns false or not.  Have you checked your SMTP configuration, is it configured properly?

Answer (score 3):

By default, **SPUtility.SendEmail()** method picks the `From address` from Outgoing E-Mail Settings in Central administration. Use `SPUtility.IsEmailServerSet` method to check if server is configured with SMTP mail settings.

You should use "**,**" instead of ";" in the **to** field in the header.

Try below **code**:

```
using (SPSite oSPSite = new SPSite("https://sharepoint.com"))  //Site collection URL
            {
                using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPSite.OpenWeb("News"))  //Subsite URL
                {
                    StringDictionary headers = new StringDictionary();

                    headers.Add("from", "dmsadmin@mydomain.in");
                    headers.Add("to", "user11@incompany.com,user2201@incompany.com");
                    headers.Add("cc","user33@incompany.com");
                    headers.Add("subject", "Welcome to the SharePoint");
                    headers.Add("fAppendHtmlTag","True"); //To enable HTML format

                    System.Text.StringBuilder strMessage = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                    strMessage.Append("Message from CEO:");

                    strMessage.Append("<span style='color:red;'> Make sure you have completed the survey! </span>");
                    SPUtility.SendEmail(oSPWeb, headers, strMessage.ToString());

                }
            }
```

Read more:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c0218d90-967c-401b-b458-adea50cb3bbd/sputilitysendemail-send-email-to-multiple-users?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious
- http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/01/how-to-send-email-using-sputility-sendemail.html#ixzz4Lj2O1cgZ

Comment: This worked well.  Once caveat here.  I found that in my implementation (certainly there are differences between the farms) -- when I included `from` in the `headers` dictionary, the `SendEmail` method returns `true` but the message is *not delivered*.  However, by removing / commenting out that one line.  It works for me.   Hope that helps.