# Unable to Send Email from SharePoint Code Behind

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, development, email, spfx-webparts

I am unable to send emails from SharePoint code behind. I've tried the following code:

```
public static void SendEmail(SPWeb spWeb, string Subject, string message, string ToName, string ToEmail)
{
    StringDictionary messageHeaders = new StringDictionary();
    messageHeaders.Add("from", "bpm@abfoods.com.pk");
    messageHeaders.Add("to", ToEmail);
    messageHeaders.Add("subject", Subject);
    messageHeaders.Add("content-type", "text/html");

    string Body = "";
    Body += "Dear " + ToName + ",";
    Body += "<br/>" + message + "<br/>Regards,<br/>Administrator";
    bool blnIsEmailServerSet = SPUtility.IsEmailServerSet(spWeb);
    bool result=false;
    try
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
        {
            result = SPUtility.SendEmail(spWeb,false,false, ToEmail,Subject, message);
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }  
}
```

[Unable to send email through SPutility.sendemail](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/195443/unable-to-send-email-through-sputility-sendemail) 
http://emailfromsharepoint.blogspot.com/2012/04/send-email-from-sharepoint.html

didn't help me.

**blnIsEmailServerSet**  is returning true but **result** variable is returning false when trying to send email.

Kindly help.

Sendemail method is returning false, why???

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Also tried the following but didn't work:

```
public static void SendEmail(SPWeb spWeb,string Subject, string message, string ToName, string ToEmail)
    {

        StringDictionary messageHeaders = new StringDictionary();
        messageHeaders.Add("from", "bpm@abfoods.com.pk");
        messageHeaders.Add("to", ToEmail);
        messageHeaders.Add("subject", Subject);
        messageHeaders.Add("content-type", "text/html");

        string Body = "";
        Body += "Dear " + ToName + ",";
        Body += "<br/>" + message + "<br/>Regards,<br/>Administrator";
        bool blnIsEmailServerSet = SPUtility.IsEmailServerSet(spWeb);
        bool result=true;
        //try
        //{

            //SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
            //{
            //     result = SPUtility.SendEmail(spWeb,true,true, ToEmail,Subject, message);
            //});
            string webUrl = spWeb.Url;
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate ()
            {
                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        result = SPUtility.SendEmail(web, messageHeaders, message);
                    }
                }
            });
        //}
        //catch (Exception ex)
        //{

        //}


    }
```

Comment: I've debugged the complete code, there's no any exception although SPUtility.SendEmail method is returning false which is being saved in result variable

Comment: What `ToEmail` value is? One or few? External addresses?

Comment: Do you receive other notifications (such as welcome to sp groups)?

Comment: @AlexZh there's only one email in ToEmail variable

Comment: @AlexZh No I didn't receive such notifications

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
string webUrl = spWeb.Url;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            //result = SPUtility.SendEmail(web, true, true, ToEmail, Subject, message);
            result = SPUtility.SendEmail(web, Subject, message);
        }
    }
});
```

UPD: why did you use false params?
[image]

You may need to configure outgoing emails in your farm:

[Configure outgoing email for a SharePoint Server farm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/outgoing-email-configuration)

[SharePoint 2013 Step by step: Setup for Outgoing Email Setting with SMTP virtual server (Part 2)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30688.sharepoint-2013-step-by-step-setup-for-outgoing-email-setting-with-smtp-virtual-server-part-2.aspx)

Comment: Can you please explain what is the difference between your answer and my code?

Comment: You need to recreate SPSite/SPWeb objects inside `RunWithElevatedPrivileges` scope (with new permissions).

Comment: tried your code, still did not receive any email :(

Comment: I did some changes in answer.

Comment: still didn't work. I've added the complete code in my update.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/outgoing-email-configuration - if your SMTP server does not allow anonymous connections

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30688.sharepoint-2013-step-by-step-setup-for-outgoing-email-setting-with-smtp-virtual-server-part-2.aspx

Comment: This is already configured